# How does %m work in $display system task?

Tags: verilog

I want to understand the usage of `%m` in the `$display` system task in Verilog.

This is sample code given in the book. It would be better if someone explains this with more examples as it seems unclear in the book.

```
//the highest-level module called top. No argument is required. This
//is a useful feature)
$display("This string is displayed from %m level of hierarchy");
-- This string is displayed from top.p1 level of hierarchy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free IEEE Std 1800-2012, section 21.2.1.6 *Hierarchical name format* states:

> The %m format specifier does not accept an argument. Instead, it
>   causes the display task to print the hierarchical name of the design
>   element, subroutine, named block, or labeled statement that invokes
>   the system task containing the format specifier. This is useful when
>   there are many instances of the module that calls the system task.

Here is an example:

```
module top;
   buff b0 (.buf_in(1'b0), .buf_out());
endmodule

module buff (
   input  buf_in,
   output buf_out
);
   wire  a;
   inv i0 (.in(buf_in), .out(a      ));
   inv i1 (.in(a     ), .out(buf_out));
   initial $display("Inside hierarchy %m");
endmodule

module inv (
   input  in,
   output out
);
   assign out = ~in;
   initial $display("Inside hierarchy %m");
endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
Inside hierarchy top.b0
Inside hierarchy top.b0.i0
Inside hierarchy top.b0.i1
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. One thing, I need to ask(I am a beginner at verilog) that does the instantiation line is a blocking statement?

Comment: @user10143594 You really should be asking that as a separate question. "Block" has at least two unrelated meanings in English. 1. to put into a group. 2. to prevent moving or advancing.

Comment: I am referring blocking as executing itself first and transferring control to next statement?